# Fortescue, degrees of freedom

Tags: vectors

In 1918 C.L. Fortescue wrote his important paper, "[Method of Symmetrical Co-ordinates Applied to the Solution of Polyphase Networks](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FortescuesTheoremForAThreePhaseUnbalancedSystem/)". In the [paper's abstract](https://vdocument.in/fortescue-1918-methodofsymmetricalpdf.html) he says, "...the number of symmetrical systems required to define the given system being equal to its **degrees of freedom**."

**My question:**  It seems to me that each of the 3 phase phasors has 2 degrees of freedom because I need 2 coordinates to locate each of them on the x-y axis.  So, for a three-phase set of voltages there are 6 degrees of freedom.  The above implies only 3 degrees of freedom. Right?

Background:  For a three-phase power system with steady-state sinusoidal voltages $\overrightarrow{V_A}, \overrightarrow{V_B},$ and $\overrightarrow{V_C}$ we can represent these 3 phase voltages on a [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) diagram as below:

[image]

Using Fortescue's method (we call it symmetrical component method today) we can convert those 3 phase voltages into 3 symmetrical sets of phasors as shown below.  The positive sequence set has the same phasor rotation order (e.g. A-B-C) as the phase set and are all equal in magnitude and separated by $120°$.  The negative sequence set has opposite phase rotation (e.g. A-C-B) and are all equal in magnitude and separated by $120°$.  The zero sequence set are all equal in magnitude and in-phase.

[image]

The original phase phasors are easily found by adding the respective components (I've not attempted to draw the phasors perfectly for this example).

$\overrightarrow{V_A}=\overrightarrow{V_{A1}}+\overrightarrow{V_{A2}}+\overrightarrow{V_{A0}}$

$\overrightarrow{V_B}=\overrightarrow{V_{B1}}+\overrightarrow{V_{B2}}+\overrightarrow{V_{B0}}$

$\overrightarrow{V_C}=\overrightarrow{V_{C1}}+\overrightarrow{V_{C2}}+\overrightarrow{V_{C0}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I count 6 degrees of freedom for your second method as well. $|V_{A1}|$, $|V_{A2}|$, the positive phase, the negative phase, and two components for $V_{A0}$. Note that it does not say that the phases of the positive sequence are equal to the phases of the negative sequence, or that the magnitudes are the same between sequences (only within a particular sequence).

Comment: I agree with you.  It seems he was loose in his terminology when he said in his paper, "...the number of symmetrical systems required to define the given system being equal to its degrees of freedom".  Later he gets specific and clarifies.